# Is it possible to implement one-to-many WebRTC video room using Twilio Video API?

Tags: webrtc, twilio, one-to-many, twilio-api, webinar

Is it possible to implement one-to-many WebRTC video room using Twilio Video API? One publisher and many subscribers. Webinar.

Comment: As I've said in my [answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47059947/is-there-any-limit-for-number-of-participants-in-a-room-in-twilio-video-api), Twilio Video is not built for broadcasting or webinars. I think you're looking for a different solution here.

Comment: Yes it is. You can see here that Twilio can support up to 50 participants: https://www.twilio.com/video Our experience so far has been that if you're trying to connect a larger number of participants, particularly if they have variable internet connections and in different regional zone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[philnash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28376/philnash) answered in the related [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47059947/is-there-any-limit-for-number-of-participants-in-a-room-in-twilio-video-api) that it's impossible at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a group room instead of a peer-to-peer room?
This is possible, and [they announced in May'17](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/05/announcing-programmable-video-group-rooms.html) an increase in the number of users per room up to 50.

In their documentation and tutorials there is an example on how to start a group room and how to configure it. See this [link](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/rooms-resource#example-3-create-a-group-room-enable-recording-and-set-a-status-callback-url). You can see how to implement it on different languages. :)

---

EDIT:

So I don't think you can create the room specifying a user id who would be the presenter, and then automatically all others who join would be just spectators.

Now, when joining a room with `Video.connect`, you can specify options for audio and video, like:

```
var Video = require('twilio-video');

// Connect to the Room with just audio
Video.connect('my-token', {
  name: 'my-room-name',
  audio: true
});
```

You can see more on how to join and the options you can specify [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/getting-started#connect-to-a-room). So you could always wrap this in your code, and force every other viewer to not send video.

Comment: Group type makes many-to-many room as far as I see. Any participant can send and/or receive audio/video streams. I'm wondering if there a way to limit (on server-side) the group to one and only one sender-participant and many-participants who can just receive strems?

Comment: Alright, edited my answer with some stuff you could do to achieve what you want. Other than that, I don't think they support what you want to achieve with just passing options when creating the room.